# Retrieve deleted tweets in twitter4j

Tags: twitter, twitter4j

I need to retrieve all deleted tweets from a specific user.

I'm working on java by using Twitter4j

Is there any solution?

Comment: I dont think you can access deleted tweets.

Answer (score 0):

You can't get deleted tweets. The best approach could be use the streaming API and get the tweets from an user, and if the user doesn't delete the tweet immediately you will get it and you can do whatever  you want.
 If you try to retrieve a tweet that was eliminated with their ID you will get an error.